# PHP include file that includes a file strange problem!

Tags: php, variables, include, nested, visibility

I face a strange problem including php files. Let me show you the code:

```
// constants.php
$MYSQL_HOST_PORT = 'localhost:3306';

// functions.php
include 'constants.php';
function getVar()  {
    echo $MYSQL_HOST_PORT;
}

// doSth.php
include 'functions.php';
echo $MYSQL_HOST_PORT; // The variable is visible and echoed normally as expected!
echo getVar(); // The variable is not echoed! its "".
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is a scope issue, not an include issue. Functions have their own scope in PHP. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: OK! Its a scope issue! You see I m coming from c++, obj-c, etc! Thank you! Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, the `echo` in `echo getVar();` won't ever print anything, because `getVar` doesn't return a value.

Secondly, if you (for some reason) want `getVar()` itself to work correctly, you need to add a `global $MYSQL_HOST_PORT;` line, to make it look for `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT` in the global scope.

Comment: Were `getVar()` to actually echo something besides an unset variable, running `echo getVar()` would still result in something being echo'd though the function name is misleading.

Comment: `echo getVar()` *would* echo something, but that specific `echo` wouldn't be causing any output.

Comment: this is an example of my problem. Even if do `return $MYSQL_HOST_PORT` the problem will still remain.

Comment: See the second part of my answer, or Phil Brown's answer. You're declaring `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT` in the global scope. Normally, a function will only "see" variables that are declared in its own local scope, so as far as `getVar()` is concerned, `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT` doesn't exist. One way around this is to add a `global` declaration for that variable inside the function, so PHP will look for it in the global scope. (Avoiding the global variable entirely would probably be preferable, though).

Comment: Thanks... didn't know about that scope issue - new to php and little strange for me!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than globalising the `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT` variable, why not simply make it a constant?

```
// constants.php
define('MYSQL_HOST_PORT', 'localhost:3306');
```

Provided `constants.php` is included, you can reference the `MYSQL_HOST_PORT` constant anywhere.

As indicated in [zerocrate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615624/php-include-file-that-includes-a-file-strange-problem/5615644#5615644), the issue is a scoping one. The enclosed scope of the `getVar()` function does not include `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT`.

Comment: +1, or make it an environment variable to put in the webserver config, and reference it using `getenv()`.

Comment: I will use the define finally! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One thing that I can see wrong is that with the line `echo getVar();` you are not getting a return value from the function so you can simply write `getVar();` by itself.

Comment: The `$MYSQL_HOST_PORT` variable is not in scope of the `getVar()` function so it's not ever going to work as-is.